# Redirecting output of command to file in awk

Tags: awk

1. I need to redirect output of only a particular command within awk to a file.
2. I need to access the array outside the if.

**What I've tried:**

```
awk '
{
  if (condition)
  {
    array[FNR]=$1;
    print array[FNR];
    df home/user/loc1 home/user/loc2 > file1.txt
  }
  fi
  print array[]
}' /home/user/testfile.txt
```

**Errors I'm getting:**

```
awk: cmd. line:18:   df home/user/loc1 home/user/loc2 > file1.txt
awk: cmd. line:18:                                                     
                                                            ^ syntax error                                                                                                                                                    


awk: cmd. line:20:     print array[]
awk: cmd. line:20:                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:20: fatal: invalid subscript expression
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing shell and awk syntax. E.g. there is no `fi` in awk, and in awk you need to use `system(...)` to issue shell commands.

Comment: But moreover, it isn't 100% clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can add some more realistic details.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, this is the completely wrong approach. Describe what you want to do (not how you want to do it) with sample input and expected output for more help.

Comment: @danfuzz not necessarily, you could also use getline to issue commands.

Comment: @Jidder Indeed, and I apologize for not being 100% comprehensive. My main point was that the code above was absolutely *not* how to issue a shell command.

Comment: Can you add some input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for,

```
awk '
{
    if (condition)
    {
        array[FNR]=$1;
        print array[FNR] # >> file2.txt (use this if you want to print to a file)
        system("df home/user/loc1 home/user/loc2") >> file1.txt # Not sure why you want to run df shell command inside awk
    }
} END { # after the entire test file is read you can do your calculations below
    for (i in array) print array[i];
}' /home/user/testfile.txt
```